# Vuejs: Typing $refs values

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a Vuejs (3) project using Typescript.
I'm trying to avoid relying on the type `any` when using `$refs`:

```
const el = (this.$refs['target'] as any).$el
```

It triggers the following warning:

```
warning  Unexpected any. Specify a different type  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
```

Any idea what type I can use instead of any ?

EDIT:
I don't want to disable my eslint rule :)

Comment: Normally, you don't need a `?`. What is the error message here?

Comment: I've just edited my qustion

Comment: Thanks. As you can see in the error message, you are violating ESLint's `no-explicit-any` rule.
You can disable this rule in the esLint configuration file.

Comment: I haven't checked for Vue3, but for Vue2 if it's a Vue component, which presumably it is as you're using $el, you can use the interface `Vue` or `VueConstructor` instead of `any`

Comment: @steve16351 Cheers mate, that's what I was looking for, if you submit this as an answer, i'll accept it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the ref refers to a Vue component (since you're using `$el`), you can use the interfaces `Vue` or `VueConstructor` which ship with Vue instead of `any`. This will give you access to the basic Vue properties of the component like `$el`, `$data` etc., though not specific methods and properties you've added yourself to the component.

This will keep ESLint happy as it's using something more specific than `any`.